# Can i detect and prevent JavaScript-driven redirect from within Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

Basically, i want to make Firefox obey "Warn me when web sites try to redirect or reload the page" user preference. Currently, this is really open sesame for any kind of doorway writers etc.

Please find the detailed description of this misbehaviour in [related superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/391832/is-there-firefox-preference-for-controlling-javascript-redirect).

Comment: You won't be able to distinguish a "JavaScript-driven redirect" from a regular link click - which means that the warning will come up way too often.

Comment: @WladimirPalant, well, i was hoping for more fine control than channel observer provides, eg: some kind of hook on Location setters... BTW, thanks for the great(est) extension :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Object.watch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) to intercept changes of some properties like `window.location`:

```
function onLocationChange(id, oldval, newval)
{
  if (confirm("Do you want to navigate to " + newval + "?"))
    return newval;
  else
    return oldval;
}
wnd.watch("location", onLocationChange);
wnd.document.watch("location", onLocationChange);
wnd.location.watch("href", onLocationChange);
```

You would have to similarly intercept assignments to other [`window.location` properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties) like `host` or `pathname`. The big disadvantage of this approach: there can be only one watcher. If the page installs its own watcher or simply calls `wnd.unwatch("location")` all your detection will be gone.

How to get to the window before any page JavaScript has a chance to run depends on whether you are using the Add-on SDK or whether you have a classic add-on. If you are using the Add-on SDK then you use the [`page-mod` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html) with `contentScriptWhen` parameter set to `start`. In the code example above you replace `wnd` by [`unsafeWindow`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/dev-guide/addon-development/content-scripts/access.html) (the window has to be accessed directly, otherwise it won't work).

In a classic add-on you register an observer for the [`content-document-global-created` notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications#Documents). Here you also have to access the window directly:

```
var wnd = XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(subject);
```

See [documentation on `XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCNativeWrapper#Unwrapping_an_object).

Answer (score 1):

A "JavaScript-driven redirect" would be done by using the `window.location` property. All you would need to do is replace that property's `setter` function as soon as the page loads.

Here is a John Resig blog post on defining setters and getters for properties. http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/

I wasn't able to override the default `window.location` setter using client side js, but it may be possible using a more privileged extension environment though.

Comment: The `window.location` property cannot be manipulated, intentionally. Privileged code can't do it either, so this won't work.

Comment: I'm not entirely surprised. So the only way to probably accomplish this would be to process all scripts before they run and replace instances of `window.location` with a new property that would include the warning when set and then call `window.location`. Kind of a hack.